# How to log every input and output and write to file in Bash?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, command-history

I am often on assignment and sometimes I forget to document my work.

E.g. write down output from different one-off tools.

Is there a way to automate that via `.bashrc`?

So I open up a new shell, it automatically creates a new log file (like `day-month-year-#`) and dumps everything in there. Also, it'd be great if I could actually see the output in the window.

Also: a lot of the output is colorized, is it possible to preserve that?

PS: disk space is not an issue ;)

Comment: To save all terminal commands and output, in color,  by running `script`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `script` utility should address your needs: It captures terminal I/O to a file. It is part of most Linuxes and Unixes by default, here's the start of its `man` page:

```
NAME
   script - make typescript of terminal session

SYNOPSIS
   script [options] [file]

DESCRIPTION
   script makes a typescript of everything displayed on your ter‐
   minal.  It is useful for students who need a  hardcopy  record
   of  an  interactive  session as proof of an assignment, as the
   typescript file can be printed out later with lpr(1).

   If the argument file is given, script saves  the  dialogue  in
   this  file.  If no filename is given, the dialogue is saved in
   the file typescript.
```

So in particular note that when you exit from the `script` session you'll find a file called `typescript` with a record of your session. For example,

```
$ script
Script started, file is typescript
$ echo blah
blah
$ exit
exit
Script done, file is typescript
```

You've now exited the `script` session and can view the result,

```
$ cat typescript 
Script started on 2021-03-09 20:24:40+0000
$ echo blah
blah
$ exit
exit

Script done on 2021-03-09 20:24:47+0000
$
```

Answer (score 0):

If [`.bash_history`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-bash-history-commands-and-expansions-on-a-linux-vps) is not what you want, you can use [`asciinema` utility](https://asciinema.org/), a free and open source solution for recording terminal sessions.

You can integrate it to start each time when you start your session and record all inputs and outputs, then save it into the file.